# persistent_undo works for vimrc file, but not for other files

Tags: persistent-state

Are there any permission settings that need set on a file to get persistent undo to work? I close and open my vimrc file and I can keep hitting the u key to see my previous edits. But it does not work for production code files. Any ideas what could be the issue?

Edited to Add:

Here is a sample of my .vimrc:

```
" Turn persistent undo on. This means that you can undo even when you close a
" buffer/VIM.
if has("persistent_undo")
  if isdirectory(expand("~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir"))
    set undodir=~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir
  elseif isdirectory(expand("~/vimfiles/temp_dirs/undodir"))
    set undodir=~/vimfiles/temp_dirs/undodir
  else
    echomsg "ERROR: undodir does not exist or is not writable."
  endif

  set undofile
endif
```

My .vimrc has 644 permission and is owned by snrub:snrub.
An example of a file that does not have persistent undo would be `/var/www/html/sites/all/modules/custom/mymodule/mymodule.module` (this is a Drupal 7 installation).

This file has 664 permission and is owned by apache:apache. User snrub is a member of the apache group, so I do have write permission on the file.

`verbose set undodir` gives the following:

```
undodir=~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir
    Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

...which is a directory that does exist.

Comment: I think the viminfo file is responsible for persistent undo. Also the undo setting (or possibly undodir; i dont remember)

Comment: Make sure you set undodir

Comment: The `'undodir'` setting is probably the answer to this question... But unfortunately it's too vague right now to be able to offer a good answer. How do you set the undo variables? (In other words, how do you enable persistent undo)? You mentioned the "production" code files, what is different about those in particular (in your environment) that could affect the behavior of undo? If you manage to ask a more specific question, you'll be likely to get a great answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out many different ways of opening and editing the file, it appears the issue is that with the "production code" (.module) file, the user snrub was not the owner of the file. I guess in order for persistent undo to work, the user editing the file must be the owner. And `chmod` file permissions are irrelevant.

Works:

`vim filename.module` for file owned by `snrub:snrub`

`sudo vim filename.module` for file owned by `root:root`

Does not work:

`vim filename.module` for file owned by `apache:apache`

`sudo vim filename.module` for file owned by `apache:apache`

Answer (score -2):

Persistent undo is controlled by [:h 'undofile'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27undofile%27) option, it's off by default.

If it's on, vim store undo history under [:h 'undodir'](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27undodir%27) when writing a buffer to a file, and restore undo history from the same file on buffer read.

Open your vimrc, and execute

```
verbose set undofile?
```

It should tell you where it was set last time.

---

**Personal opinion about persistent undo:**

Not sure if it's a good idea to turn on `'undofile'`, if it's off, you can hold `u` or execute `:undo 0` to undo all the changes made in current session, if it's on, you have to use `:earlier 1h` family command instead. It also cost more and more memory as your undo history getting bigger and bigger.

Personally I prefer manual style undo history read and write:

```
set undodir=$HOME/.vimundo//

command WriteUndo setlocal undofile | w | setlocal noundofile
command ReadUndo setlocal undofile | e | setlocal noundofile
```

You can also use [:h :rundo](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#%3Arundo) and [:h :wundo](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html#%3Awundo) to manually read and write undo history if you prefer not to store the undo history file in `undodir`.

**Update to address OP's update**

It's a bit surprise that no error would occur if `undodir` doesn't exist.

You setting is over complicated, AFAIK, `persistant-undo` was added in `vim7.3`, that's long long long ago, I also don't see the point of checking multiple undo directories, you might want to simplify it to

```
set undofile undodir=~/.vim/temp_dirs/undodir
if !isdirectory(&undodir)
  call system('mkdir -p ' . &undodir)
endif
```

Comment: Well I like to have my .vimrc file work with both Windows and Linux, since I use both on a regular basis. So I test for both .vim (Linux) and vimfiles (Windows) directories.

Comment: @MrSnrub It's possible to set `undodir` to multiple directories, first found one will be used. I'm not familar with windows vim setting, maybe you can use `~/.vimundo` as `undodir` for both windows and linux ?

Comment: I don't think your reservations about  persistent undo are warranted. I've been using it trouble-free for years. I never clean the `'undodir'` yet on my primary Win box there's only 28 MB in there from a total of 500 files...largest is 2MB...memory usage from this is never a concern. And that's with an `'undolevels'` cap of 3000...three  times the default value.

Comment: @MrSnrub FYI I use the same vimrc on one machine for both Cygwin and Windows with only a handful of platform specific settings segregated with `if has('win32')...else...fi`. including `/some/path/.undo/win` and `/some/path/.undo/cyg` as the Windows and Cygwin `'undodir'` values respectively. Works well.

Comment: @BLayer Thanks for clearing the concern on memory. To be honest, I have never turned it on as I am afraid that `u` to old changes would cause trouble, especially when make changes with `cdo` on N files, does it ever give you any trouble?

Comment: I use a pretty wide swath of Vim functionality (day-to-day as well as a result of answering questions here) but I don't think I've used `cdo` more than a handful of times. I"ll keep an eye out and, time permitting, take a closer look and let you know if anything comes up. (Everything else that I've done, though, has played nice with my always-on persistent undo.)

Comment: @BLayer Thanks,  I decide I to give it a shot.

Comment: Cool. Hope everything works well. You might want to check out [undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree). Depending on how you interact with the history it can be quite convenient.